# Insert Array Data Into MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

An attempt to insert data to an sql database via sql/php and a third party program.

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

$auth_host = $GLOBALS['auth_host'];
$auth_user = $GLOBALS['auth_user'];
$auth_pass = $GLOBALS['auth_pass'];
$auth_dbase = $GLOBALS['auth_dbase'];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=$auth_host;dbname=auth_dbase;charset=utf8', '$auth_user',                   '$auth_pass');

$query = mysql_insert("account", $_POST);
mysql_query($query); 

mysql_close($db);
?>

<?php
function mysql_insert($table, $inserts) {
$values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($inserts));
$keys = array_keys($inserts);

return mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES    (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');
}
?>
```

I believe my problem to be in there php statement.  The last bit is to clear out the data.

Comment: use pdo or mysqli_* functons instead of mysql_*

Comment: i suggest you use PDO prepare statements. `$sql->prepare($query)` then execute `$sql->execute($query);`

Comment: you have closed the connection before the insert.. `mysql_close($db);`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you refrain using `mysql` and start using `PDO` / `mysqli`, im not sure if i truly understand your question. but you can try below code if you want to insert data to your database.

```
$query = mysql_insert("account", $_POST);
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
```